# How to restart Android app within Espresso test?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I am using Espresso with Kotlin for the UI test automation. I am trying to find a proper way to restart the app during the test and start it again, so the test scenario is the following:

- start the app, go to login page
- force close the app and open it again (basically restart it)
- check some stuff etc

The way our UI tests are organized:
there is a test class where I have rules

```
val intent = Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity::class.java)
        .putExtra(UI_TEST_INTENT, true)

@get:Rule
val rule = ActivityScenarioRule<MainActivity>(intent)
```

there Before/After functions and tests functions in this class

What I want is to have generic ***restartApp*** function in separated class, let's say ***TestUtils*** and to be able to call it at any point of time, when is needed.
So far I didn't find a solution. There are some similar questions on stackoverflow, but I am not sure I understand how to work with the answers I found, like this:

```
with(activityRule) {
finishActivity()
launchActivity(null)
```

}

Since ActivityTestRule is deprecated and documentation asking to use ActivityScenarioRule, I tried this:

```
@get:Rule
val rule = ActivityScenarioRule<MainActivity>(intent)

private fun restart() {
    rule.scenario.close()
    rule.scenario.recreate()
}
```

but it gets java.lang.NullPointerException

another option is

```
private fun restart() {
    pressBackUnconditionally()
    Intents.release()
    ActivityScenario.launch<MainActivity>(intent)
}
```

it works, app restarts but I can not interact with the app anymore, because for some reason there are two intents running now

Would be great to get an answer I can work with (I am quite new to Espresso)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The solution is found:

```
private fun restart() {
    Intents.release()
    rule.scenario.close()
    Intents.init()
    ActivityScenario.launch<MainActivity>(intent)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing.

Comment: isn't activityRule.scenario.recreate() enough? meaning it closes the app and reopens it, or am I missing something

Comment: what is UI_TEST_INTENT means.. and what it is used for... also does this clear singleton instances?

Comment: This seems to be not initiate the application class again... i want all my singletons as well as application class to be recreated again. is there any way for this usecase

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the author's answer has some excess code. The following is enough

```
activityScenarioRule.scenario.close() 
ActivityScenario.launch(YourActivity::class.java, null)
```